# Lebesgue Integral over set of measure of zero

Tags: measure-theory

Is it defined for a non-measurable, non-negative function? It would make sense, as clearly $s=0$ is a simple function, and $s\leq f$ for any $f$, whether it is measurable or not. So the clasically defined $$\int_E f\,d\mu=\sup\left\{\int_E s\,d\mu\ : \ s \text{ is a measurable simple function }, s\leq f \right\} $$

would exist and be equal to $0$, if $E$ is of measure $0$.

I don't think it is defined for non-measurable functions, but what I wrote above would seem like a convenient addition - couldn't it help with the whole idea of "almost everywhere" and make it easier/simpler, at least in some cases?

Comment: it has also an extended definition for negative functions. see the wiki article.

Comment: To answer your initial question, the Lebesgue integral is only defined for measurable functions. In your definition, it is not only assumed that $f$ is non-negative, but also that it is measurable. What if $f = \chi_F$ where $F$ is a non-measurable set? This function is certainly non-negative, but it is not measurable. "Integrating" this function would give us $\mu(F)$, which is not defined. Not sure if this helps or answers the other part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are thinking about this the wrong way. One should adopt the definition:

$$\int_E f d \mu := \int_{\mathbb{R}} f \chi_E d \mu.$$

Because the Lebesgue measure is complete, $f \chi_E$ really is a measurable function, so the right side is well-defined, and provides a suitable definition of the left side. Specifically you do indeed get $\int_E f d \mu = 0$.

An alternative is to make $E$ a measure space in its own right by equipping it with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ consisting of elements of $\mathcal{M}$ which are subsets of $E$, and the restriction of $\mu$ to $\mathcal{A}$. Then again because the Lebesgue measure is complete, $\mathcal{A}$ is actually the power set of $E$, and so $f$ is measurable as a function from this new measure space. The end result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, because by the definition of $\int_E f\,d\mu$, it is limit of $\int_E s\,d\mu$ for $s$ *simple* measurable function, and a simple measurable function is by definition is a linear combination of indicator functions of measurable sets, and its the measurability of this sets thats ensures the measurability of the simple functions, which make all the rest make sense. If these sets are not measurable, you cannot conclude to the measurability of the simple "wannabe" measurable function.

Comment: In the set of simple measurable funcions smaller or equal to f, there is at least s=0. This and any other simple measurable function in there, will clearly have integral 0. sup{0} = 0. It seems to me like the only problem here, is that by definition, it's simply not defined for f-non measurable.